# Phone not receiving text messages unless messaging app happens to be open when message is sent

Tags: sms

My phone only receives text messages if the messaging is open when they are sent.

Messages that are sent at other times (eg when I've just opened a different app) never show up on my phone, even when I later open the messaging app.

(I tested this by sending myself texts from a different phone.)

This is the case no matter which SIM card is in the phone (tried 3, multiple carriers).

My phone is a BLU Advance 4.0 L2 running Android 6.0, and I'm using the default messaging app called Messages.

Edit: 
I tried using Textra instead and had the same issue.

I tried clearing the cache partition from recovery mode. The problem persists.

How might I fix this?

Comment: Can you check if the issue happens only with the default SMS app or any SMS app. Try with Google Messages and let us know.

Comment: The default app was Google Messages. I just tried Textra as well; same issue.

Comment: Sometimes clearing the phone cache in the recovery may solve this issue.